# Parsing JSON Swift

Tags: ios, json, xcode, parsing, swift

I am working on an app that displays the live Bitcoin price. I am using 2 APIs to do this - one plaintext, and one JSON. I am having a bit of trouble with the JSON API.

Here's a bit of my Swift code

```
func BTCFallback(){

    var string2 = currencySelector.currentTitle


    var url = NSURL(string:"https://bitpay.com/api/rates/" +  (string2)!)
    var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)


    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:fallback)

    var data = NSData(contentsOfURL:url);
    let value = NSString(string: USD.text).doubleValue / NSString(data:data, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding).doubleValue

    // Define JSON string
    var JSONString = "\(data)"

    // Get NSData using string
    if let JSONData = JSONString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false) {

        // Parse JSONData into JSON object
        var parsingError: NSError?
    if let JSONObject = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(JSONData, options: nil, error: &parsingError) as? [String: AnyObject] {

        // If the parsing was successful grab the rate object
        var rateObject: AnyObject? = JSONObject["rate"]

        // Make sure the rate object is the expected type
        if let rate = rateObject as? Float {
            println("rate is \(rate)")
            BTC.text = "\(rate)"
        }
    } else {

        // There was an error parsing the JSON data
        println("Error parsing JSON: \(parsingError)")
        BTC.text = "err1"
    }

}






}
```

In the above code, currencySelector.currentTitle is equal to an ISO currency code, for instance USD. BTC.text is a UI element.

The expected behavior is that the code will set the counterpart of "rate" as the text of BTC.text. In case this helps, the API returns something like {"code":"USD","name":"US Dollar","rate":376.71}. I would want, using the above example, to have BTC.text set to 376.71

Here's what's happening: the consoe gives the error 
`Error parsing JSON: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x16eb0f60 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.})`

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does the data look like before it is passed into the parser?

Comment: 1. Why are you converting the data to a string and then back to data prior to  `JSONObjectWithData`? 2. println the JSON string `JSONString` and examine the JSON and verify that it is valid JSON.

Comment: @Hyperbole The JSON looks like {"code":"USD","name":"US Dollar","rate":376.71} from the API. A link to the API is https://bitpay.com/api/rates/USD

Comment: @rocket101 It can't look like that, otherwise the parser wouldn't barf.  Make sure you're actually passing a data object that has data in it.  Put a breakpoint after `dataUsingEncoding()` and check it there.

Comment: @Zaph  when I println JSONString, it gives <7b22636f 6465223a 22415544 222c226e 616d6522 3a224175 73747261 6c69616e 20446f6c 6c617222 2c227261 7465223a 3430392e 3738347d> . Any ideas why? There is a link in the above comment if you need to take a look at the API...

Comment: @Hyperbole when I println JSONString, it gives <7b22636f 6465223a 22415544 222c226e 616d6522 3a224175 73747261 6c69616e 20446f6c 6c617222 2c227261 7465223a 3430392e 3738347d> . Any ideas why? There is a link in the above comment if you need to take a look at the API...

Comment: JSONString is an NSData object.  That's why it prints like that.

Comment: @rocket101 Yeah, that's the string encoded.  Is there a reason why you're not passing the `NSData` object from the `contentsOfURL` call directly into `JSONObjectWithData()`?  Something might be lost in translation.

Comment: @Hyperbole No reason - Will try like that. One moment

Comment: @Hyperbole If you need, I did a breakpoint too: http://postimg.org/image/k0lsfv6ih/

Comment: @Hyperbole Sorry, I'm new to swift. How can I adjust the code like you suggested?

Comment: @rocket101 Try changing the first parameter of `JSONObjectWithData` to `data`, like this: `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: &parsingError)`

Comment: Converting the hex data to a string: {"code":"AUD","name":"Australian Dollar","rate":409.784} which is valid JSON with the top level object being a dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is all a matter of handling the returned data and de-serialization.

Here is example code, note that the handling of Optionals should be better, this is just to demonstrate the basic code. For example purposes I used a simple synchronous web call.:

```
var url: NSURL! = NSURL(string:"https://bitpay.com/api/rates/AUD")
var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
var response: NSURLResponse?
var error: NSError?
var data: NSData? = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response, error:&error)
println("data: \(data)")

if let data: NSData = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse:&response, error:&error) {
    println("data: \(data)")

    var parsingError: NSError?
    if let rateDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: &parsingError) as NSDictionary? {
        println("rateDictionary: \(rateDictionary)")

        // If the parsing was successful grab the rate object
        if var rateString: AnyObject = rateDictionary["rate"] {
            println("rateString: \(rateString)")

            // Make sure the rate object is the expected type
            if let rate = rateString.floatValue {
                println("rate is \(rate)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ouput:

```
data: Optional(7b22636f 6465223a 22415544 222c226e 616d6522 3a224175 73747261 6c69616e 20446f6c 6c617222 2c227261 7465223a 3430372e 39393137 7d)

rateDictionary: {
    code = AUD;
    name = "Australian Dollar";
    rate = "407.9917";
}

rateString: 407.9917

rate is 407.992
```