# How to access elements of JSON Array in Swift 2

Tags: swift

I have a string, dataString, containing the following json information:

```
{"products":[
 {"DBID":"2954","ScanID":"143","Name":"Cables","Count": 7,"Info":""},
 {"DBID":"5551","ScanID":"129","Name":"Batteries","Count": 24,"Info":""},
 {"DBID":"7143","ScanID":"003","Name":"Media","Count": 49,"Info":""}
]}
```

How can I

1. iterate through this data using Swift 2 to calculate a total of the "Count" field for all products?
2. access the data elements of a specific "products" slot.  For example, if I know I need to retrieve the "Name" of the product in slot 1, how can I access it directly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing JSON Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26551029/parsing-json-swift)

Comment: I would suggest making your life easier and using https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON & https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/Alamofire-SwiftyJSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the sum of all count you can use `sum` operator of iOS. For more collection operator check this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html). You need to change your code like this

```
do {
    //Here jsonStr in your json String
    let data = jsonStr.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let dic = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
    let proArr = dic["products"] as! NSArray
    let sum = proArr.valueForKeyPath("@sum.Count")
    print(sum) //Print sum of the all count
    print(proArr[0]["name"]) //To print name of first products
}
catch let e as NSError {
    print(e.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: When I try your answer, it prints "Optional" with the array's data.  Thus, print(proArr[0]["name"]) prints "Optional(Cables)".  I tried to unwrap and then print, but it still does the same.

Comment: try to print like `print(proArr[0]["name"]!)`

Comment: It still does the same thing.

Comment: That gives a compile error "Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type 'AnyObject'

Comment: If I do the following, it works, though I'm not sure why it is necessary as it appears that I'm using optional binding to unwrap an optional that is already forced-unwrapped.

    if let theName = proArr[i]["Name"]!
    {
     print(theName)
    }